# Can Git Extensions or Git Source Control Provider work side by side with AnkhSVN?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ankhsvn, git-extensions

I am trying to move my projects to Git but I am not very comfortable with it yet. I want to use Git Extensions or Git Source Control Provider but I am not sure if it will work with AnkhSVN. Of course I will be using only one of them on a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will work with other Source Control Provider (SCP), but you need to be sure your `.sln` file (solution) doesn't declare directly what SCP is wants to use.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 9.00
# Visual Studio 2005
Project...
EndProject
Global
 GlobalSection(Subversion) = preSolution
 SourceControlProvider = Subversion
 EndGlobalSection
...
EndGlobal
```

Check also your project file (`.proj`):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <SccProjectName>Subversion</SccProjectName>
  <SccLocalPath>Subversion</SccLocalPath>
  <SccAuxPath>Subversion</SccAuxPath>
  <SccProvider>Subversion</SccProvider>
 </PropertyGroup>
...
```

If those files (`.sln` or `.proj`) mention explictely the SCP, then you might have an issue, even if you select the right plug-in (see "[Using Git with Visual Studio 2010, an introduction](http://blog.discountasp.net/using-git-with-visual-studio-2010-an-introduction-2/)") in the options:

[image: plug-in selection for source control in Visual Studio]

Visual Studio would still use SVN for your project when you open its solution (ie all the git menu and options would be deactivated immediately)